Why is the tipping point between a serial and parallel plan not exactly the point where the serial plan is costed less?
For the example data...

/*Quick and dirty generation of some rows of data*/
SELECT value as [orderid], 
       1 as [custid], 
       1 as [empid], 
       1 as [shipperid], 
       getdate() as [orderdate], 
       'abcdefgh' as [filler]
INTO dbo.Orders
FROM generate_series(1,10000000)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_cl_od] ON [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [orderdate] ASC
)

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Orders WITH FULLSCAN

And the following query
SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE orderid <=7601715 AND 1=1 /*Prevent simple parameterisation*/

Then on my dev machine (SQL Server 2022, DOP of 4) the IO cost of the clustered index scan is 46.8853 regardless of serial or parallel plan.
And the CPU cost of the scan is 11.0002 in the serial plan and  2.75004 in the parallel one
So I was expecting the tipping point between the plans to be when the parallelism operator exceeded 8.25016 (a threshold reached when estimated rows going into it is around 4.5 million). In reality at the point this actually occurs the cost for the gather streams operator is 13.0501 (around 3 million rows higher than I expected).
If SQL Server isn't using overall plan cost as the tipping point what is the actual logic?
(XML for estimated plans on pastetheplan)


The tipping point is as you expect. The showplan information doesn't accurately reflect optimizer costing.
The first two queries (parallel natural and serial hinted) both have a cost of 62.6855 at optimizer output.
Showplan shows a cost of 57.8855 for the serial plan (4.8 less).
The optimizer output for the serial plan has a Filter above the Scan. This Filter is pushed down into the Scan as a residual (non-SARG) predicate by a post-optimization rewrite. The rewrite loses the cost of the Filter.
You can see the expanded plan (without pushdown) using trace flag 9130:

The Filter has a cost of 4.8.
